# Python Multiple Initial Conditions

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am fairly new to programming.  I've picked up some R and Matlab in classes, but I'm trying to increase my familiarity with Python.  I am trying to code a model that will numerically approximate systems of differential equations given multiple initial conditions.  The code I currently have is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameters
sigma=10
gamma=1
alpha=50
delta=2.1
# initial conditions
B=[100,200]
P=[1,10]
t=0
# counter
dt=0.00005
stop=1
# vector
Bstor=[]
Pstor=[]
tstor=[]
# let's go

for i in B:
    for j in P:
        while t<=stop:
            Bstor.append(i)
            Pstor.append(j)
            tstor.append(t)
            i=i+(sigma-gamma*i-alpha*i*j)*dt
            j=j+(alpha*i*j-delta*j)*dt
            t=t+dt

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(tstor,Bstor,'-b')
plt.plot(tstor,Pstor,'-r')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.show()
```

This will do the math quite nicely, but only for the first values of P and B. How do I get the equations to run for each possible combination (`P[0],B[0]; P[1],B[0]; P[1],B[0]; P[1],B[1]`)?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by first values? the nested `for` will make the required permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong with the iterations. It's a minor bug. You are just forgetting to re-initialize `t = 0` before the inner `for`. That's why it is running once as `t <= stop` holds for only one iteration of inner loop. That's why you are getting the first values.

Comment: Thanks, C Panda!  After following your advice and ironing out another bug in the iterations, it worked like a charm!